# Connection goes idle and disconnects Mongodb from AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, aws-lambda

MongoDB idle problem is giving me nightmares. It fails without reason, it doesn't trigger disconnecting event or error. it just disconnects in the middle of API call.

I have tried reading blogs and old questions as well and tried it all, still the situation doesn't help at all.

This is my database connection code:

```
function connect () {

return mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_DB_URI, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    reconnectTries: Number.MAX_VALUE,
    reconnectInterval: 1000,
    bufferMaxEntries: 0, // and MongoDB driver buffering
    bufferCommands: false, // Disable mongoose buffering
    ha: true, // Make sure the high availability checks are on
    haInterval: 10000 // Run every 10 seconds
  })
}

if (process.env.MONGO_DB_URI) {
  connect()
}
```

with it I am also logging several events for the database.

```
db.on('connecting', () => {
  debug(`mongoose : connecting `)
})

db.on('connected', () => {
  debug(`mongoose : connected`)
})
db.on('open', () => {
  debug(`mongoose : open`)
})
db.on('disconnecting', () => {
  debug(`mongoose : disconnecting`)
})
db.on('disconnected', () => {
  debug(`mongoose : disconnected`)
})
db.on('close', () => {
  debug(`mongoose : close`)
})
db.on('reconnected', () => {
  debug(`mongoose : reconnected`)
})
db.on('error', (err) => {
  debug(`mongoose : error`, err)
})
db.on('all', () => {
  debug('mongoose: all')
})
db.on('fullsetup', () => {
  debug(`mongoose : fullsetup`)
})
```

Also before API call I check for the database connection from a middleware.

```
app.use(async (req, res, next) => {
  log.info('Ready State: ' + mongoose.connection.readyState, {
    action: 'App.ConnectionCheck'
  })
  if (mongoose.connection.readyState !== 1) {
    log.info('try to reconnect', {
      action: 'App.ConnectionCheck'
    })
    await connect()
    next()
  } else if (mongoose.connection && mongoose.connection.db) {
    await Promise.race([
      mongoose.connection.db.admin().ping(),
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          reject(new Error('Race condition failed'))
        }, 1000)
      })
    ]) 
    .then(async d => {
      log.info('ping successful: ', d)
      if (d.ok !== 1) {
        await connect()
      }
    })
    .catch(async e => {
      log.error('Ping Failed ', {
        error: e
      })
      await connect()
    })
    next()
  } else {
    next()
  }
})
```

But still sometimes a call comes in, and first query is made, but i dont get a response back and my API times out.

This is what my logs look like notice the time it takes to reconnect.

```
2020-08-10 16:30:55.465 (+05:00)        34c5812c-5446-4c0f-bddf-c4ca8a0117cb    INFO    ----------------- BODY END ------------
2020-08-10 16:30:55.466 (+05:00)        34c5812c-5446-4c0f-bddf-c4ca8a0117cb    INFO    Mongoose: meetings.countDocuments({ appntId: '<APP_ID_HERE>', '$or': [ { deleted: true }, { createdAt: { '$gt': new Date("Mon, 10 Aug 2020 11:30:45 GMT") } {})
Mon, 10 Aug 2020 11:30:55 GMT timify:db-handle:index mongoose : disconnected
Mon, 10 Aug 2020 11:31:15 GMT timify:db-handle:index mongoose : connected
Mon, 10 Aug 2020 11:31:15 GMT timify:db-handle:index mongoose : reconnected
END RequestId: 34c5812c-5446-4c0f-bddf-c4ca8a0117cb
END RequestId: 34c5812c-5446-4c0f-bddf-c4ca8a0117cb
REPORT RequestId: 34c5812c-5446-4c0f-bddf-c4ca8a0117cb  Duration: 30030.13 ms   Billed Duration: 30000 ms       Memory Size: 10
Max Memory Used: 172 MB
```

**Version**:

- "mongoose": "^5.4.17"
- "nodejs": "12.x"
- "mongodb-driver": "3.1"

I have seen another post regarding this issue, but my environment is different and that question is back from 2016.

Comment: What part of this is in lambda? all of it?

Comment: its an express app, for API hosted on lambda

Comment: Found any solution on this? and what happens if bufferCommands is set to True

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered a similar problem with running an Express app on AWS Lambda.

The error message I got was :

```
MongooseError: Cannot call `users.find()` before initial connection is complete if `bufferCommands = false`. Make sure you `await mongoose.connect()` if you have `bufferCommands = false`.
```

My current connection settings that work are

```
mongoose
    .connect(mongoConnectionString, {
        useNewUrlParser: true ,
        useCreateIndex: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        keepAlive : true,
        bufferMaxEntries: 0 // and MongoDB driver buffering
    }
);
```

With trial and error I have managed to track down the connection error to

> bufferCommands: false

command and commenting it out made it work for me.

I couldn't find any reason behind this issue through the [mongoose documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#buffering) about buffering options, but you can try turning buffering off globally by,

```
mongoose.set('bufferCommands', false);
```

Hope this solution helps.

EDIT : Setting bufferCommands to false globally, resulted in the same error.

Comment: as you can see in my setting I already have them off

Comment: Yes I have seen it, setting it to off is the reason behind the problem. Either do not use that setting at all or comment it out.

Comment: Note that `bufferMaxEntries` doesn't exist for mongoose 6. You can confirm this in their typedef.